# Running su noninteractively?

Tags: su

So, I got locked out of a server (sshd seems to have stopped responding). I got a reverse shell (added a jenkins job that gives me a reverse shell), but I've hit a snag - su wants a terminal, and refuses to run.

So, is there a way to run su noninteractively, or some other way of escalating to my normal user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out I didn't google this quite enough when I caved and made this question.

The answer is to do as https://serverfault.com/a/495154/68820 says, and run

`python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/sh")'`

inside of the reverse shell, which gets you a pty.

Doing this, I was able to su to my normal user, and restart the sshd.

Comment: And as you restart ssh will be wise to add jenkins in sudo :)

Comment: but jenkins doesn't normally ever need sudo. doing so would be a security risk

Comment: No risk if you do not provide passwordless sudo access. And provide ability to sudo to standard user, not root

Answer (score 0):

Try with sudo. This is the contemporary (and much safe way)

Of commands like this:

```
echo "password"|su - -c "command"

echo -e "password\n"|su - -c "command"
```

Comment: the jenkins user doesn't have sudo access

Comment: Add to /etc/sudoers file the appropriate record for jenkins user

Comment: which I can't do without access to a more priviledged user

Comment: I am sure the machine in question have sysadmin to take care. So contact him/her and ask for those records

Comment: I am the sysadmin, the sshd died, so this is my only access to this box

Comment: try something like: echo "password"|su - -c "command" Or echo -e  "password\n"|su - -c "command"

Comment: regarding your edit, no, su will not run without a terminal, regardless.

Comment: also, I solved this via another solution already

Comment: So add your answer here (as own answer to the question)